# How can I use a variable as an argument to a function, specifically unz() in R

Tags: r, variables, scope, arguments, unzip

I am writing an R function that reads CSV files from a subdirectory in a ZIP file without first unzipping it, using read.csv() and unz().

The CSV files are named with leading 0 as in 00012.csv, 00013.csv etc.

The function has the following parameters: MyZipFile, ASubDir, VNum (a vector e.g. 1:42) which forms the filename.

What I want is to use the variable PathNfilename in unz().

```
# Incorporate the directory in the ZIP file while constructing the filename using stringr package
PathNfilename <- paste0("/", ASubDir, "/", str_pad(Vnum, 5, pad = "0"), ".csv", sep="")
```

What works is:

```
csvdata <- read.csv(unz(description = "MyZipFile.zip", filename = "ASubDirectory/00039.csv"), header=T, quote = "")
```

What I need is something along these lines of this:

```
csvdata <- read.csv(unz(description = "MyZipFile.zip", filename = PathNFileName), header=T, quote = "")
```

The error that I get is:

> Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In open.connection(file, "rt") :
>         cannot locate file '/ASubDir/00039.csv' in zip file 'MyZipFile.zip'

I'd like to understand why I'm getting the error and how to resolve it. Is it a scoping issue?

Comment: What OS are you using? Most likely you do not have a directory named `ASubDir/` on your machine's root directory, which is what you are specifying when you use a leading forward slash in `/ASubDir/...`. Is `ASubDir/` in your current working directory?

Comment: OS: Windows10. When I use filename = "ASubDirectory/00039.csv", I can read the CSV file into a dataframe. However, when I try to pass the variable PathNfilename (which resolves to "ASubDirectory/00039.csv"), I get the error message mentioned earlier.

Comment: in your example your `PathNfilename` seems to resolves in "**/**ASubDirectory/00039.csv" with a `/`, not "ASubDirectory/00039.csv".
Try PathNfilename <- file.path("ASubDir", paste0(str_pad(Vnum, 5, pad = "0"), ".csv"))

Answer (score 0):

Try with some `PathFilename` without the leading `/`

```r
ASubDir <- "ASubDirectory"
Vnum <- 1:5

PathNfilename <- file.path(ASubDir, 
                           paste0(str_pad(Vnum, 5, pad = "0"), ".csv")
)

PathNfilename
#> [1] "ASubDirectory/00001.csv" "ASubDirectory/00002.csv"
#> [3] "ASubDirectory/00003.csv" "ASubDirectory/00004.csv"
#> [5] "ASubDirectory/00005.csv"
```